# Is it possible to add another dataset on my trained model in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I already trained a custom person detector which doesn't work well on detecting perons on aerial footage which is because my dataset lacks on aerial images of a person. Can I continue the training using the latest checkpoint and add another dataset (different tfrecord file) for my model or do I have to restart the training using the updated dataset?

I retrained the Inception model to detect persons only since there no other way to remove the other 89 objects from the pretrained model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely start from a checkpoint using another dataset. However, it might not be a good idea to train only on a subset of your data due to the tendency of neural nets to forget what they'e already learned (a problem known as [catastrophic forgetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_interference)). It's probably a better idea to create a new dataset that includes both your old and new data, and either pick up from the checkpoint using those data (similar to how you fine-tuned the Inception model), or start the training process over.